# How to properly unit test FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, unit-testing

With the `unittest` module, how can I test `FileNotFoundError` is raised when opening a file as follows:

```
func(filename):
    try:
        file = open(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        exit()
```

Unittest module

```
class TestFunc(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_func(self):
        self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError, func, "no_exist.txt")
```

Resulting error

> AssertionError: FileNotFoundError not raised by func

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are swallowing the exception inside your exception handler, so there is no way your calling code (the unit test) can know that the error has been raised, all it sees is that your code has run, and exited.

Consider re-raising as in :

```
func(filename):
    try:
        file = open(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Whatever else you want to do 
        raise
```

Better still, your unit test shouldn't really be depending on that file not existing - unit tests should be self contained by definition. Consider mocking the open method so you have more control.

Comment: but unittests should not only test correct behavior. having corner cases in the arguments (as empty lists,..) or error handling must be tested too.

Comment: @rocksportrocker Absolutely agree. What I'm suggesting is that the OP should mock out the open method so he can be sure that it will throw a FileNotFoundError, rather than rely on the file system being in a particular state.

Comment: ah, ok. What also works is to create a file with random name in a temporary folder. A fixture for this would also do the trick. I somehow use mocking only as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Use context manager for Exception

> Changed in version 2.7: Added the ability to use assertRaises() as a context manager.
>
> If only the exception argument is given, returns a context manager so that the code under test can be written inline rather than as a function:

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException):
    do_something()
```